# Using local proxy to specify used NIC on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, proxy, network-adapter, bindings

I'm running Windows 7 and have 2 NIC installed, both are connected to the Internet (nic#1 LTE, nic#2 DSL). Windows 7 will only allow me to specify a binding order and a metric on which interface to chose but i can't specify this on an application level.

My Idea was to use a local proxy server and use the proxy server whenever i want to use nic#2.

I tried wingate and free proxy, both applications will let me chose the interface i want to use but this setting seems to have no effect?

This is how i configured the applications:

[image]

[image]

Is what i'm trying to do in anyway possible?

Comment: If i use VirtualBox and set it to Bridged Mode i can select nic#2 and that works! So now i can chose if i want a VM Proxy or just do everything directly in the VM. I'm quite happy with this solution...

Answer (score 0):

Bindings in WinGate affect where you can connect TO WinGate from.

If you want to specify what interface WinGate uses to connect out, you need to set that on the Gateways tab (next one)